# Web-based time tracking app with task nesting

Tags: web-apps, time-management, web-services, cloud-service

I'm looking for a cloud/web-based time tracking app - like TimeCamp or Toggl - with:

1. The "unlimited tree structure" of TimeCamp
2. The stability and robustness of Toggl
3. The main common features of both, like report generation, and free-form notes on individual entries

---

1. TimeCamp's "unlimited tree structure" refers to how they can nest projects, such that you can have e.g. `Client / Project / Subproject_level_1 / Subproject_level_2 / Task`. By contrast, Toggl only has `Client / Project`.
2. By stability and robustness (like Toggl), I mean it doesn't add time incorrectly - either temporarily on the screen when you switch tasks; or permanently when it adds your times together.

A monthly fee is acceptable, as this is for business use.

Answer (score -2):

If there are others who are looking for a similar solution, I have just discovered [timecamp.com](https://timecamp.com). With it's free web app or mobile app, you can start one of your nested task.

Comment: TimeCamp is explicitly discussed and rejected in the question.

Comment: You are right. There must be something wrong with my reading ability. On the other hand, the question helped me by mentioning the rejected product. I've been looking for a nested task time tracking app for a long time.

Comment: If you get to using it, please reply here and let us know if you observe the bugs such as described in the question. It's been a while; maybe my reasons for rejecting it aren't still valid.